# Table headers and column mis-aligned

Tags: html, css, alignment

The data in the column does not align with the headers.

I have tried to set the display in the head to

```
 display: table-header-group;
```

to no avail.

Thanks

```css
  table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 25px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  background-color: bisque;
  table-layout: fixed;

  thead {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: table-header-group;

    tr {
      background-color: #009879;
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: left;
    }
  }
  tbody {
    tr:nth-of-type(even) {
      background-color: whitesmoke;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th id="monthName">Months</th>
          <th class="header" colspan="2">June</th>
          <th class="header" colspan="2">July</th>
          <th class="header" colspan="2">August</th>
          <th class="header" colspan="2">September</th>
          <th class="header" colspan="2">October</th>
          <th class="header" colspan="2">February</th>
          <th class="header" colspan="2">March</th>
          <th class="header" colspan="2">April</th>
          <th class="header" colspan="2">January</th>
          <th class="header" colspan="2">May</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="question">x</td>
            <td class="answer">95</td>
            <td class="answer">73</td>
            <td class="answer">73</td>
            <td class="answer">56</td>
            <td class="answer">63</td>
            <td class="answer">68</td>
            <td class="answer">80</td>
            <td class="answer">86</td>
            <td class="answer"></td>
            <td class="answer"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="question">y</td>
            <td class="answer">68</td>
            <td class="answer">85</td>
            <td class="answer">64</td>
            <td class="answer">56</td>
            <td class="answer">96</td>
            <td class="answer">100</td>
            <td class="answer"></td>
            <td class="answer"></td>
            <td class="answer">89</td>
            <td class="answer">79</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="question">z</td>
            <td class="answer">61</td>
            <td class="answer">59</td>
            <td class="answer">86</td>
            <td class="answer">44</td>
            <td class="answer">86</td>
            <td class="answer">65</td>
            <td class="answer"></td>
            <td class="answer">73</td>
            <td class="answer">51</td>
            <td class="answer">92</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

I tried to align the content of the body to the headers so that it looks like a spreadsheet but the answers get bunched together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `colspan="2"` is making the header row 21 columns wide (1 + 10*2), when your three data rows are 11 columns wide.

Answer (score 0):

Remove colspan,

I hope, It will help you

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="monthName">Months</th>
        <th class="header">June</th>
        <th class="header">July</th>
        <th class="header">August</th>
        <th class="header">September</th>
        <th class="header">October</th>
        <th class="header">February</th>
        <th class="header">March</th>
        <th class="header">April</th>
        <th class="header">January</th>
        <th class="header">May</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="question">x</td>
          <td class="answer">95</td>
          <td class="answer">73</td>
          <td class="answer">73</td>
          <td class="answer">56</td>
          <td class="answer">63</td>
          <td class="answer">68</td>
          <td class="answer">80</td>
          <td class="answer">86</td>
          <td class="answer"></td>
          <td class="answer"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="question">y</td>
          <td class="answer">68</td>
          <td class="answer">85</td>
          <td class="answer">64</td>
          <td class="answer">56</td>
          <td class="answer">96</td>
          <td class="answer">100</td>
          <td class="answer"></td>
          <td class="answer"></td>
          <td class="answer">89</td>
          <td class="answer">79</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="question">z</td>
          <td class="answer">61</td>
          <td class="answer">59</td>
          <td class="answer">86</td>
          <td class="answer">44</td>
          <td class="answer">86</td>
          <td class="answer">65</td>
          <td class="answer"></td>
          <td class="answer">73</td>
          <td class="answer">51</td>
          <td class="answer">92</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 25px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  background-color: bisque;
  table-layout: fixed;
   }


  thead {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: table-header-group;
    width: 50px;
     }

    tr {
      background-color: #009879;
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
    }
  
  
  td {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

  tbody {
    tr:nth-of-type(even) {
      background-color: whitesmoke;
    }
  }
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th id="monthName">Months</th>
          <th class="header" >June</th>
          <th class="header" >July</th>
          <th class="header" >August</th>
          <th class="header" >September</th>
          <th class="header" >October</th>
          <th class="header" >February</th>
          <th class="header" >March</th>
          <th class="header" >April</th>
          <th class="header" >January</th>
          <th class="header" >May</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>

          <td class="question">x</td>

            <td class="answer">95</td>
            <td class="answer">73</td>
            <td class="answer">73</td>
            <td class="answer">56</td>
            <td class="answer">63</td>
            <td class="answer">68</td>
            <td class="answer">80</td>
            <td class="answer">86</td>
            <td class="answer"></td>
            <td class="answer"></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>

          <td class="question">y</td>

            <td class="answer">68</td>
            <td class="answer">85</td>
            <td class="answer">64</td>
            <td class="answer">56</td>
            <td class="answer">96</td>
            <td class="answer">100</td>
            <td class="answer"></td>
            <td class="answer"></td>
            <td class="answer">89</td>
            <td class="answer">79</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>

          <td class="question">z</td>

            <td class="answer">61</td>
            <td class="answer">59</td>
            <td class="answer">86</td>
            <td class="answer">44</td>
            <td class="answer">86</td>
            <td class="answer">65</td>
            <td class="answer"></td>
            <td class="answer">73</td>
            <td class="answer">51</td>
            <td class="answer">92</td>

        </tr>
        
        
        
        
        
        

    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Try like this. You can change the width of the columns if you want, according with your needs.